# How to avoid arxiv converting http URLs into "this http URL" link in the abstract meta data

Tags: arxiv

I have an abstract that contains URLs which I would like them to appear "as-is" as they are part of the content. However, arxiv automatically modify the URLs (in the meta data) that I included in the abstract to a link with the title: `this http url`.

Is there any way I can prevent this and make the URLs to appear as they are? Because they are part of the story and asking the user to click on the link is not what I want.

I looked at arxiv and found this [here](https://arxiv.org/help/prep):

> We automatically convert these into an active link reading "this ftp
>   URL" and an http URL into a link reading "this http URL" (try for a
>   grammatically sensible substitution). The location of related files or
>   information should be given here. Also, you should add a space to
>   separate any periods or text following a URL from the URL itself, so
>   that it is not interpreted as part of the URL. For example, the
>   comment

Is there anyway to avoid automatically converting the URLs in the abstract?

Comment: It seems they don't make this replacement in the preview, so I can't test it out, but I wonder what happens if you put the link in text in math mode, e.g. $\text{www.google.com}$.

Comment: @Anyon If I write the abstract in Latex it appears as Latex. So I have to write it as text. Yes, unfortunately, this does not appear in the preview. Similarly, writing it in latex appears fine in preview but when it is published, it appears as Latext code.

Comment: They're working on it: https://github.com/arXiv/arxiv-base/pull/132

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a domain name in the URL, try formatting one or more dots in TeX (MathJax), as in `foo$.$com`.

I ran into the same issue, as my abstract mentioned "coverage.py" (and ".py" happens to also be the top level domain for Paraguay).

A few things that don't work:

- formatting the whole domain in LaTeX/MathJax;
- using backticks around the whole domain (``);
- encoding the dot as HTML identity (`&#46;`);

If you are a Python programmer and would like to experiment, look at the function named "[urlize](https://github.com/arXiv/arxiv-base/blob/develop/arxiv/base/urls/links.py)".
After cloning and installing the [arxiv-base](https://github.com/arXiv/arxiv-base) repository, you can try out strings with:

```
from flask import Flask
from arxiv.base.urls import urlize

app = Flask('test')
with app.app_context():
   print(urlize("foo bar xyzzy.com baz"))
```